# No access to form.inputName.$dirty where inputName is inside a directive template with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a directive that has a template with an input element. Normally you can access formName.inputName.$dirty when the input is outside of a directive with isolated scope. But when you put it inside the directive with isolated scope, I have no way to access the outside form. Even if I could access it, I don't think the inputName input control is accessible on the form either. I need to look at the $dirty, $invalid flags on the input control and have their ng-invalid and ng-dirty class names available. Is there anyway to do this?

A plunk showing the outline of what I am doing is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5kMTN7R9OTN7sFrFRknE?p=preview).

More info: I can find the form on the $scope.$parent but there is a {{inputName}} field in it instead of the value of inputName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, accessing `scope.$parent` from an isolate scope is not a good idea.

If you only want to use this for validation and only locally inside the directive's template (i.e. within the context fo the isolate scope), you can use **[`ngForm`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)**, which has the same functionality as `form` from an Angular perspective, but is not subject to `form`'s limitation (e.g. it can be nested).

Change the simple-input template like this:

```
div class="form-row" ng-form="simpleInputForm" 
    ng-class="{'error':inputBlur && !isActive(inputName) && 
                       simpleInputForm.simpleInput.$dirty && 
                       simpleInputForm.simpleInput.$invalid}">
    ...
    <input type="text" name="simpleInput" id="{{inputName}}"
    ...
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/C9ig9yyBY720jvWKQWwk?p=preview)**.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to access the input element from outside the directive, so you're solution won't work for me. And I'm open to other ways to do this without using scope.$parent.

Comment: So your solution will work if I add a name attribute on the simple-input element, then pass name to the input control inside the directive. http://plnkr.co/edit/5ngt2WoqJMzkvIosPnyc?p=preview

Comment: Basically, you don't even have to pass the name to the directive. Just setting a name on `<simple-input>` does it: http://plnkr.co/edit/PEl3WRyIQjhfoxftUqM5?p=preview